# Regex: how to simplify numbers?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Given numbers with a large number of decimals, such:

```
213.094783481320923547301
093.7914840234913405
...
```

**How to only keep the first 3 decimals, so the result is :**

```
213.094
093.791
```

Comment: `\d+\.\d{3}` -- how about that?

Comment: When you have +1000 such strings within a JSON, yes.

Comment: @Hugolpz Adding the tag was helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

Find:

```
(\d+\.\d{3})\d+
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply something like:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}
```

Or perhaps you want to allow up to 3 decimal places:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:-

```
\d+(\.\d{1,3})?
```

Answer (score 1):

this can also works for `(\d+)\.(\d{3})\d+`